# Excel- SUM formula not working on IF formula converted data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel I used an if formula to change values to 1 or 0. This worked fine. I tried to sum the data from J2:J2103 but it always shows a zero for the total. I used auto sum and it showed the total to be zero also.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You're going to need to give a lot more information than this. As is, Your question is entirely unclear. Could you provide sample data, the formula you are using, the expected results of the formulas, and what the formulas you have are returning? With this information, you'll probably be able to get a useful answer.

Comment: Try a simple case. Like J2:J3 not J2:J2013

Comment: You should at least include the IF formula in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your formula returns "1" or "0" then the quotes make those text values and `SUM` will ignore text.

Remove the quotes and use just 1 and 0 and the sum function will sum accordingly...

.....alternatively, as counting 1s is the same as summing them you could use `COUNTIF` to count "1"s without changing your original IF formula, e.g.

`=COUNTIF(J2:J2013,"1")`